# how to change navbar bootstrap height and make the text keep in the middle?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, height, navbar

There're so many ways I've tried to edit  bootstrap navbar. Actually, for changing the color, and costuming its height had already done. However, the texts left behind.[this is the case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cv7i.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

If you want to make the navbar less than 50px you need to override css property `min-height` in `.navbar-default` from bootstrap.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruiz/aprw086f/)

***Note:***

This will affect your hamburger menu in smaller devices though. You could make it smaller in 768px and above without defining the `min-height` in `.navbar default`, but doing it in a media query, like this:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
 .navbar-default {
  min-height:30px;
 }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

When you change your navbar's height, vertical aligning the anchors can be done doing the following:

1. Remove the top and bottom padding from the anchors.
2. Set the anchor's line-height with the same value as your navbar's height.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruiz/7aucjtbz/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.navbar-default {
  height: 80px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}
.navbar-form {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: actually i want to make the height become small. It doesn't work, if  the (line)-height less than 50 px. 

By the way, Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to satisfy what you're asking for, please check it out. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Actually I tried height:80px and line-height:40px. Well that centered text in the navbar